# $a,b,c$ be three complex numbers satisfying $|a|=|a-b|=3\sqrt3,|a+b+c|=21$,$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=0$. Find $|b|^2+|c|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $a,b,c$ be three complex numbers satisfying $$|a|=|a-b|=3\sqrt3\\|a+b+c|=21\\a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=0$$ Find $|b|^2+|c|^2$.

I started by squaring the first relation to get $|b|^2=a\bar{b}+b\bar{a}.$ Then $$|a+b+c|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+a\bar b +b\bar a +a\bar c+c\bar a+b\bar c+c\bar b=441.$$ The last relation says $$(c+b\omega+a\omega^2)(c+b\omega^2+a\omega)=0.$$ WLOG, $c+a\omega^2+b\omega=0$, so $-\bar c=\bar a\omega+\bar b \omega^2$. So putting the values of $c,\bar c, a\bar b+b\bar a$, I got $$|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|b|^2+|a|^2+|b|^2-2a\bar b\omega^2-2\bar a b \omega=441.$$ Now I’m completely stuck. Please help to proceed.

Comment: HINT.-$|a-b|=3\sqrt3 \iff a-b=3\sqrt3\text { and } a-b=-3\sqrt3$

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers so how can we write this?

Comment: Is there a solution?

Comment: @user170231 $|ab+ac+bc|=21^2/3=147$

Comment: @Lozenges Right, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=0$ geometrically implies that $a,b,c$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle (*proof at bottom of this answer*). It follows that
$$|a-b|=|b-c|=|c-a|=|a|$$
Just as you obtained from $|a-b|=|a|$, $a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b=|b|^2$, combining other two with $|a|$ will give respectively $$a\bar{c}+\bar{a}c=|c|^2$$ and
$$b\bar{c}+\bar{b}c=|b|^2+|c|^2-|a|^2$$
Using these in $|a+b+c|^2=21^2$, $|b|^2+|c|^2$ will be found.

> Answer : $|b|^2+|c|^2=21^2/3=147$

---

**Statement :** Complex numbers $a,b,c$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle $\Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=0$.

**Proof :** I prove $\Leftarrow$ direction. $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=$$(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)(a+b\omega^2+c\omega)=0$.
So either $(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)=0$ or $(a+b\omega^2+c\omega)=0$

(A) $a+b\omega+c\omega^2=0 \Rightarrow a+b\omega-c-c\omega=0 $ $$\frac{a-c}{b-c}=-\omega = e^{-i\pi/3}\Rightarrow (a-c)=(b-c)e^{-i\pi/3}$$
meaning $a,b,c$ form the vertices of a positively oriented equilateral triangle i.e., $\triangle ABC$ has vertices $A,B,C$ in anticlockwise sense.

(B) $a+b\omega^2+c\omega=0 \Rightarrow a+b\omega^2-c-c\omega^2=0 $ $$\frac{a-c}{b-c}=-\omega^2 = e^{+i\pi/3}\Rightarrow (a-c)=(b-c)e^{+i\pi/3}$$
meaning $a,b,c$ form the vertices of a negatively oriented equilateral triangle i.e., $\triangle ABC$ has vertices $A,B,C$ in clockwise sense. $\quad \blacksquare$

Comment: I know that if a,b,c are vertices of equilateral triangle then the last relation holds but not that when it holds, the vertices must be on an equilateral triangle. Please provide its proof as well.

Comment: @Maths Added the proof.

Comment: Yes now it’s perfectly clear.